# C# Error ORA 00907: Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: oracle

My error:

> ORA 00907: Missing Right Parenthesis

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_TD_USER
(

  USER_ID                 INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME               VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD                VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_BY              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE            DATE NOT NULL,
  MODIFIED_BY             VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  MODIFIED_DATE           DATE NOT NULL,
  IS_ACTIVE               CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION             VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT TBL_TD_USER PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)

);
```

Comment: This is not the way to down vote a question, im just a beginner and the error i got i just posted it as it is no rocket science needed in understanding the question. if you cant help others, lets not demotivate them by doing such stuff, common sense needed to understand questions BTW

Comment: Above mentioned comment belongs to all of them, who think SO is their property!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_TD_USER    
(    
 USER_ID       INTEGER NOT NULL ,    
 USER_NAME     VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,    
 PASSWORD      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,    
 CREATED_BY    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,    
 CREATED_DATE  DATE NOT NULL,    
 MODIFIED_BY   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,    
 MODIFIED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,    
 IS_ACTIVE     VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,    
 DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,    
 CONSTRAINT TBL_TD_USER PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)    
);
```

- There's no variable type named `CHARACTER` in oracle, as an alternative, you to use `VARCHAR2` with length value in parenthesis.
- You can use `INTEGER` type without length.

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/931e0a)